# How can we detect if particular user on system is RemoteDisconnected or not?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services, window, remote-desktop

I have my schedule windows service running in a system. Within it I want to detect if particular user in same system is remote disconnected or not.

In order to achieve this, currently I am overriding OnSessionChange(..) method of **System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase** class to write status in file and when 
I need to check status, I read it from same file.

But I would like to know a better way of detecting without storing it in file?

```
class mySessionBase : ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)  
    {
        //Save the status of machine in file
         hangeDescription.Reason.ToString()
         changeDescription.SessionId
    }
}
```

Is there any window remote API available to detect the same?

Thanks in Advance

Mahen

Comment: Look at [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx) and [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838.aspx). You can retrieve user info and remote state from the latter

Comment: yes,WTSEnumerateSessions() is work for us

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this below where **WTSEnumerateSessions** API help us to get session and connection status.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111430/Grabbing-Information-of-a-Terminal-Services-Sessio